# Run a method after editing a cell on a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I am using WPF and CaliburnMicro for binding data. I want to run an Add() method every time I finished editing a cell but the problem is the property for the datagrid does not execute it.

Here is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGrid_NotifyOfPropertyChanged.Views.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGrid_NotifyOfPropertyChanged.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="ShellView" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="Numbers" CanUserAddRows="False"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public class NumbersModel
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

ShellViewModel

```
public class ShellViewModel: Screen
{
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        Numbers.Add(new NumbersModel { Number = 1 });
        Numbers.Add(new NumbersModel { Number = 2 });
    }

    private BindableCollection<NumbersModel> _numbers = new BindableCollection<NumbersModel>();

    public BindableCollection<NumbersModel> Numbers
    {
        get { return _numbers; }
        set { 
            _numbers = value;
            Add();
        }
    }

    public void Add()
    {
        double result = 0;
        foreach(var i in _numbers.ToList())
        {
            result += i.Number;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You could put your logic in the setter for Number. You should use more considered naming of properties. Always jmplement inotifypropertychanged on viewmodels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must let `NumbersModel` implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
This way you can get a notification when a property has changed. You generally *always* have to implement this interface on every class that serves as a binding source.
Data binding would work without this interface, but the performance will drastically degrade. For applications with many bindings, this will be an issue.

The solution is to listen to property changes of `NumbersModel.Number`. I therefore introduced a dedicated event `NumberChanged`.
The event `NumberChanged` is optional. You can also listen to `PropertyChanged` and then use a `switch` statement to filter the required property by property name. I think a dedicated event significantly increases readability and understanding of the context, opposed to a cluttered `switch` block.

To prevent memory leaks when removing items, you must unsubscribe from every event of `NumbersModel` your are listening to.
You therefore also need to listen to the `CollectionChanged` event of the `Numbers` collection:

**NumbersModel.cs**

```
public class NumbersModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private int number;
  public int Number
  {
    get => this.number;
    set
    {
      if (value == this.number)
      {
        return;
      }

      this.number = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
      OnNumberChanged();
    }
  }

  public event EventHandler NumberChanged;
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  protected virtual void OnNumberChanged()
  {
    this.NumberChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}
```

**ShellViewModel.cs**

```
public class ShellViewModel : Screen
{
  public ShellViewModel()
  {
    this.Numbers = new BindableCollection<NumbersModel>();
    this.Numbers.Add(new NumbersModel {Number = 1});
    this.Numbers.Add(new NumbersModel {Number = 2});
  }

  public void Add()
  {
    double result = this._numbers.Sum(numbersModel => numbersModel.Number);
    MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
  }

  private BindableCollection<NumbersModel> _numbers;
  public BindableCollection<NumbersModel> Numbers
  {
    get => this._numbers;
    set
    {
      // Unsubscribe from old collection
      if (this.Numbers != null)
      {
        this.Numbers.CollectionChanged -= OnCollectionChanged;
      }

      this._numbers = value;

      // Subscribe to new collection
      if (this.Numbers != null)
      {
        this.Numbers.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
        Add();
      }
    }
  }

  private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    switch (e.Action)
    {
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
      {
        foreach (NumbersModel newItem in e.NewItems.Cast<NumbersModel>())
        {
          newItem.NumberChanged += OnNumberChanged;
        }

        break;
      }
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
      {
        foreach (NumbersModel newItem in e.OldItems.Cast<NumbersModel>())
        {
          newItem.NumberChanged -= OnNumberChanged;
        }

        break;
      }
    }
  }

  private void OnNumberChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Add();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to run an `Add()` method every time I finished editing a cell

The way to do this using Caliburn.Micro would be to use an `EventTrigger` and an `ActionMessage` to handle the `CellEditEnding` event:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="Numbers" CanUserAddRows="False"
     cal:Message.Attach="[Event CellEditEnding] = [Action Add()]" />
```

Comment: I have tried this but the output is not what I expected. Lets say I have two instances(Number=1 and Number=2). Updating the cell in the datagrid which is bound to Number=1 and replacing it with 2 and performing the Add() method results to 3 instead of 4. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: How and when to update the source property is a different topic. Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Your original question was about how to "run the Add() method every time I finished editing a cell", wasn't it?

Comment: Cleary you don't understand "finished editing a cell". Judging from the output, the cell has not been edited at all.